# Removed from New listing and Search

Tags: kik

Our app has been removed from News and Search. We see KikBot in the logs hitting the site periodically.
After patiently waiting 48hrs, where can we open a support ticket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your rel=canonical tag has a malformed URL. It is supposed to be a URL, not a hostname.